# Regex - Match pattern A unless it matches pattern B

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to excluded some very specific routes from my MVC project.
More specifically I want to ignore all calls to .ashx pages, unless they match a certain pattern.

```
(?<!invoices\/(order|membership)\/(\d{5,})-([a-f0-9]{8}))\.ashx
```

This is the pattern I came up with, but since you can't use quantifiers in a negated lookbehind, it's not working.

Any ideas as to how I can achieve this so I can ignore my routes correctly with a call like this:

```
routes.Ignore("{*handlers}", new { handlers = "(?<!invoices/(order|membership)/(\\d{5,})-([a-f0-9]{8}))\\.ashx" });
```

Comment: Try `"^(?!.*invoices/(order|membership)/\\d{5,}-[a-f0-9]{8}).*\\.ashx"`. A `$` end of string anchor might be required at the end of this pattern.

Comment: That pattern doesn't match any of these two strings: 
invoices/membership/20005-dac8c917.ashx
nvoices/membership/20005-dac8c917.ashx
First one is corectly not matched, second one should be matched

Comment: Well, my simple test says you have some issue with the backslashes. Try using `\d` instead of `\\d` and `\.` instead of `\\.`, or just work around that with [`^(?!.*invoices/(order|membership)/[0-9]{5,}-[a-f0-9]{8}).*\[.\]ashx`](https://regex101.com/r/vL8cX1/1). Also, your regex should work, see `(?<!invoices/(order|membership)/[0-9]{5,}-[a-f0-9]{8})[.]ashx`. Try it at [RegexStorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester) that supports .NET regex syntax.

Comment: However, I am not sure if partial matches are allowed in routes.

Comment: You sir, are correct. I forgot to remove the escape characters when copying from Visual Studio.
It could be that regexstorm uses another implementation of regex than .NEt.

Comment: It does, if you post an answer, I'll accept it right away :-)

Comment: RegexStorm only supports .NET regex syntax, and it is one and unique :). As for ``\``, in `\d` the ``\`` must be a literal backslash. In C#, you may use it as `@"\"` or `"\\"`. No idea what strings you are having in the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET regex flavor does support infinite-width lookbehinds, so the only issue with *your* pattern is the double backslashes. Use `\d` instead of `\\d` and `\.` instead of `\\.`, or just work around that with character classes `[0-9]` (a digit) and `[.]` (a literal dot):

```
(?<!invoices/(order|membership)/[0-9]{5,}-[a-f0-9]{8})[.]ashx
                                ^^^^^                 ^^^
```

You can also get rid of the lookbehind, and use a lookahead anchored at the start:

```
^(?!.*invoices/(order|membership)/[0-9]{5,}-[a-f0-9]{8}).*[.]ashx.
```

The `(?!.*invoices/(order|membership)/[0-9]{5,}-[a-f0-9]{8})` negative lookahead will fail the match if a string *contains* (remove the first `.*` to make it *starts with*)  the `invoices/(order|membership)/[0-9]{5,}-[a-f0-9]{8}` pattern.